# Background colored div transition to background image

Tags: css

Hi what I am trying to do is have a  with background color and on hover it will transition to a image. I found very good example but other way around here is a link.
http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PbvFr/1/ so I need bg black and on :hover image will appear over time. I tried to do this but unfortunately the transition is not smooth. thank you for your time!!!!!!!!

```
.imageWrap {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 300px;
    moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    width: 300px;
}

.imageWrap .img {
    moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    opacity: 1;
    o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

.imageWrap:hover {
    background-image: url(5.jpg);
    moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}

.img:hover, .imageWrap:hover .img {
    moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    opacity: 0;
    o-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `the transition is not smooth`?

Comment: I mean that it does not apply any transition to the background image when you hover mouse over the div with color background the image appear instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse what he did: http://jsfiddle.net/PbvFr/102/

Change opacity from 0 to 1 rather than 1 to 0.

```
Look the CSS
```

Comment: thank you for you time almost what I need but I need the image only appear on hover, so for example first background color black and when I hover the div it bring the image.

Comment: Isn't that what my fiddle does.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PbvFr/101/)

**CSS**

```
.imgWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
    height: 500px;
    width:364px;
}

.imgWrap img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #fff;
   color: #fff;
   opacity:0;
   transition:1s;
}

.imgWrap:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
 }
```